# Link public and private variables (with write access to private variables)

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am currently rewriting C code into C++ code. While doing that I am replacing `structs` with `classes`. That means that some of the variables go from public to private. Now during the transition phase I want to do some error checking by compiling the program sometimes and running it. Thus I intended to have public and private variables at the same time, which are linked, i.e. when I write something into the private variable, the public variable also changes. Nevertheless I only want to write to the private variables by using separate functions, i.e. having the public variables as read-only variables. My current approach is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

class test_vec
{
    private:
        int x, y;
        int data[2];
    public:
        int x_ext, y_ext;
        int data_ext[2];

        test_vec(int x, int y)
        {
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;
            this->x_ext = this->x;
            this->y_ext = this->y;
        }

        ~test_vec()
        {}

        void set_x(int x)
        {
            this->x = x;
        }

        void set_y(int y)
        {
            this->y = y;
        }
};

int main(void)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";
    test_vec test(1, 2);
    printf("test has the properties (%d, %d)\n", test.x_ext, test.y_ext);//So far, so good
    test.set_x(4);
    test.set_y(10);
    printf("test has the properties (%d, %d)\n", test.x_ext, test.y_ext);//Not updated!
    return 0;
}
```

How can I change the links between the variables? At the moment I already have two pointers copied into each other, but how can I "lock" the external variable onto the internal variable?

Comment: Since you need to change client code to use the new name anyway (adding `_ext`), why not just change it to use a getter? Storing const references makes your object bigger and frankly looks weird.

Comment: Terminology nitpick: There's no sense talking about "replacing structs with classes", because there is no difference between `struct` and `class`, except the default access of members, and you make that moot by having `private:` as the first line in your class.

Comment: @Useless: They will be removed in a final clean up, but until then I would prefer to have them in order to be able to test the program during the transition phase.

Comment: Sure, but why can't you test with getters that don't add extra, temporary members to your object? Seriously, you're presumably going from `p->x` to `p->x_ext`, and I don't see how changing to `p->x()` is any harder.

Comment: I could also rename the internal variables to `p->x_int`, and leave the outside variables at `p->x`, thus not changing anything to the outside (just in that example done that way)

Comment: One of us is misunderstanding the other. There is _no benefit_ to exposing const ref members over just providing getters, unless you're trying to avoid changing existing code that uses those members. If you have to change that code anyway, just use getters.

Comment: "While doing that I am replacing structs with classes' - structs *are* classes. They simply have different default visibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it's a good design pattern since inline getters are fast but you could create constant references to your private variables:

```
class test_vec
{
    private:
        int x, y;
        int data[2];
    public:
        const int &x_ext, &y_ext;
        int data_ext[2];

        // you have to initialize the references before constructor body
        // references cannot be let uninitialized
        test_vec(int x, int y) : x_ext(this->x), y_ext(this->y)
        {
            this->x = x;
            this->y = y;

        }

        ~test_vec()
        {}

        inline void set_x(int x)
        {
            this->x = x;
        }

        inline void set_y(int y)
        {
            this->y = y;
        }
};
```

when `x` or `y` changes `x_ext` and `y_ext` follow:

```
Hello World
test has the properties (1, 2)
test has the properties (4, 10)
```

Bonus: constant references cannot be modified. That's the closest thing of a read property that you got here :)

If you don't want that restriction, just remove the `const` qualifier, but since you're encouraging encapsuation now that you have C++ I would let it as is and let the writers hit the wall on that (not to mention a good `sed`/regex replacement could refactor all your writes automatically)

Comment: You should also mention how the public references are now "read-only" because you declared them const.

Comment: @Hayt: I do not care about that, which was afaik also written in the question.

Comment: @arc_lupus while you may not care, this is a change (and also advantage) of this approach and may be something to note for others which stumble across a similar problem and read this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use references for these purposes.

Say you have this setup:

```
class myclass{

    public:

                myclass(int pa, float pb);

    int         get_a() const {return a;}
    float           get_b() const {return b;}

    void            set_a(int v) {a=v;}
    void            set_b(float v) {b=v;}

    private:
    //These are the real values, private
    int         a;
    float           b;

    public:
    //These are the references, public
    int&            ref_to_a;
    float&          ref_to_b;        
}

myclass::myclass(int pa, float pb)
    :a(pa), b(pb), ref_to_a(a), ref_to_b(b)
{

}
```

You can go like this:

```
myclass c(33, 12.3f);

c.set_a(12);
c.set_b(111.1f);

//This...
std::cout<<c.ref_to_a<<" "<<c.ref_to_b<<std::endl;
//Should be the same as this...
std::cout<<c.get_a()<<" "<<c.get_b()<<std::endl;
```

Notice the access settings: the references are public, meaning you can write and read from them. If you want them to be read only you can play with the constness.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't bother.  Just make the members public for the moment, and when you have fixed all the external references, make them private.

```
class test_vec
{
    public:   // For now.  Will become private later
        int x, y;
    public:   // For now.
        int data[2];
    public:   // For ever
        test_vec(int x, int y)
          : x(x), y(y)   // Prefer initialization to assignment.
        {
        }

        ~test_vec()
        {}

        void set_x(int x)
        {
            this->x = x;
        }
        void set_y(int y)
        {
            this->y = y;
        }

        int get_x() const { return x; }  // etc
};
```

If you really wanted to, you could make `x_ext` be a reference to const - but it's much more idiomatic in C++ to make getters be functions.

```
class test_vec
{
    private:
        int x, y;
        int data[2];
    public:
        int const& x_ext;
        int const& y_ext;

        test_vec(int x_, int y_)
          : x(x_), y(y_)
          , x_ext(x), y_ext(y)  // You *have* to use initialization here.
        {
        }

        ~test_vec()
        {}

        void set_x(int x)
        {
            this->x = x;
        }
        void set_y(int y)
        {
            this->y = y;
        }
};
```